# What's the most efficient way to input this data to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this (British dates):

| Type | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 |
| 2 | 02/01/2022 |
| 3 | 03/01/2022 |
| 1 | 04/01/2022 |
| 2 | 05/01/2022 |
| 2 | 06/01/2022 |

There are two types of column that I'm currently adding with a big for loop. The first is the number of rows of the same type with an older date and the second is the number of days between the latest row of the same type and older date and the current row (-1 if there is are no older rows of the same type).

For example the dataframe would become:

| Type | Date | Previous count | Days since latest previous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 0 | -1 |
| 2 | 02/01/2022 | 0 | -1 |
| 3 | 03/01/2022 | 0 | -1 |
| 1 | 04/01/2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 05/01/2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 06/01/2022 | 2 | 1 |

Is there a way of doing this more efficiently than a simple for loop?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the data later, you could use `df.groupby("Type")` to end up with separate DataFrames for all types. Those you can order by date and you have all the information essentially there, as the "previous count" will then be simply an increasing number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

g = df.groupby('Type')['Date']
df['Previous count'] = g.cumcount()
df['Days since latest previous'] = g.diff().fillna('-1').dt.days
```

output:

```
   Type       Date  Previous count  Days since latest previous
0     1 2022-01-01               0                          -1
1     2 2022-01-02               0                          -1
2     3 2022-01-03               0                          -1
3     1 2022-01-04               1                           3
4     2 2022-01-05               1                           3
5     2 2022-01-06               2                           1
```

*NB. I am assuming here that the input is sorted by Date*

Comment: Would that work if days are duplicate?

Comment: @rammelmueller no you'd need to mask, can you provide an example with the matching output as there are different possibilities to handle this case?

Comment: I'm not even the author of the question - just wanted to check.

Comment: @rammelmueller oops, sorry :p Yes, in this case you could mask the values with `duplicated` to only count unique days. I thought of it but can't provide an answer without knowing how this should be handled ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's really helpful! There are duplicate dates, although they're actually ordered by time as well. So if two dates are the same with the same type, the prior date should be included in the previous count and days since latest should be 0. I think this will work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
gg1=df1.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df1.Date,format="%d/%M/%Y")).groupby('Type',sort=False)

col1=gg1.cumcount()
col2=gg1.Date.diff().dt.days.fillna(-1).astype(int)
df1.assign(**{"Previous count":col1,"Days since latest previous":col2})
```

out

```
  Type        Date  Previous count  Days since latest previous
0     1  01/01/2022               0                          -1
1     2  02/01/2022               0                          -1
2     3  03/01/2022               0                          -1
3     1  04/01/2022               1                           3
4     2  05/01/2022               1                           3
5     2  06/01/2022               2                           1
```